# Scanning a String for strings

Tags: c, c-strings

I'm trying to write a function that reads in a line from a file using fgets().
After reading the line, I want to take the line apart and make it into smaller strings.
Depending on the first word in the line, the line that I read in can have 3-5 smaller strings that are separated by a white space.

Example:
Line: remove apple 12345
string1: remove
string2: apple
string3: 12345

Line: add tomato red leaf
string1: add
string2: tomato
string3: red
string4: leaf

From the example above, if 1st string is remove, I need to read 2 other strings (apple, 12345).
If the  first string is add, I need to read 3 other strings (tomato, red, leaf).

Is there anyway that I can decide the number of times to read and do this using sscanf?

```
while( fgets( buf, sizeof buf, course_file ) != NULL ){
    sscanf( buf, "%s", &string1);
    printf( "%s\n", buf );
}
```

It is not compulsory that I use sscanf, I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "decide the number of times to read".

Comment: Sorry about that. Let's make it a precise example. If the first word is remove, I need to create 3 tokens(remove, apple, 12345) and if the first word is add, I need to create 4 tokens(add, tomato, red, leaf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function typically used to tokenize strings is `strtok`, but it is not thread-safe; its modern version is [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) should be used instead.

Start tokenizing the `buf` in the first call, check the first token, and then go into one of several loops that depend on the content of the first token:

```
while( fgets( buf, sizeof buf, course_file ) != NULL ) {
    char *saveptr;
    char *tok = strtok_r(buf, " ", &saveptr);
    if (!strcmp(tok, "delete")) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i != 3 ; i++) {
            tok = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveptr);
            // Do something with the token...
        }
    } else if (!strcmp(tok, "add")) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
            tok = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveptr);
            // Do something else with the token...
        }
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can peek ahead to know if I really read in all the argument/mini-strings? I'm worried cause I'm required to handle a name field which could be any combination of first, middle and last name.

Comment: @user1043625 You can make your tokenizing logic to continue or stop based on the current token that you see. I mean, instead of a `for` loop you can use a `while`, or break out of the loop if you find a certain token or when the stream of tokens ends early.

Comment: Hmm, alright. Was wondering if there is a way for me to extract the pointer to current location of strtok_r.

Comment: @user1043625 There's a little problem with that, because `strtok_r` not only goes through the string, but also temporarily inserts terminating zeros into the original string at the next terminator. That's why going back on `strtok_r` is not easy.

Comment: I guess a while loop would do the job then. Thanks! :D